Why does the RFbeam radar sensor mention a 1K load in its datasheet?
I am working with the K-LC1a V4 radar sensor from RFbeam and looking through their datasheet, they mention using a 1K load such as under "Mixer Conversion Loss" on page 2 and and Pin Configuration on page 4. Do I need to ensure that it is driving such a load for reliable operation? I am planning on operating it in the 20 Hz to 2 kHz range for CW radar.
Looking at the Typical Signal Amplifier Application Note, it doesn't look like they are doing that, but I do see a 1k resistor to ground on the Pulsed Operation Application Note.
Also, if I do try to enable full FMCW operation, should I expect an output IF that is under 20 kHz or will that push it into the megahertz range due to the wide shift in the carrier frequency? I see the datasheet mention values for f_IF at 1 MHz at 20 MHz reference. It also seems to indicate that the load should be closer to 50 ohms at that point.


Do I need to ensure that it is driving such a load for reliable operation?

Probably not.
The IF can be used very wideband, and for that you will almost always be using a 50 Ω load. However, at low frequencies, not loading the output will give you twice the voltage output, which can save you x2 gain elsewhere. 1 kΩ is so much higher than 50 Ω that it's practically open circuit, so almost not loading the output.
Why do they show a 1 kΩ load with the pulsed amplifier?
It's usually a good idea with an AC coupled amplifier to have a DC path to ground on any node that could float, especially ones you might connect a cable to. It saves surprises.
